# Jquery autocomplete - custom html for result listing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am referring to this plugin: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

So the original structure for the results is

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to make the links inside to look something like this:

```
<a class="myclass" customattribute="something"> The item </a>
```

Please don't tell me the only solution it to edit the plugin because i don't want the same format for all autocompletes on the site.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to replace the `_renderItem` method (for the autocomplete in question):

```
$("selector").autocomplete({ ... })
   .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a class='myclass' customattribute='" + item.customattribute + "'>" + item.label + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
   };
```

(assuming the `items` in your `source` have a property called `customattribute`)

As shown in this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: oh man. I missed that in the examples there. Thanks a thousand! It works perfectly.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker +1 - you saved me a whole lot of trouble. I checked the documentation on http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#entry-examples, but it didn't say anything about `_renderItem`.

Answer (score 6):

This is also documented in jquery-ui autocomplete documentation at: [Jquery-autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

The trick is:

1. Use this jquery extension: [github Code](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions)
2. Then in autocomplete option pass

   ```
   html:true

   ...autocomplete({
   ...
   html:true
   ...
   }
   ```

   );
3. Now you can pass html(like <div>sample</div>) in "label" field of JSON output for autocomplete.

If you don't know how to add the plugin to JQuery then:

1. Save the plugin(Scott González' html extension) in a js file or download the js file.
2. You have already added the jquery-ui autocomplete script in your html page(or the jquery-ui js file). Add this plugin script after that autocomplete javascript file.

Post date: 28th July, 2013

Comment: This solution works like a charm. just download the file named "jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js" inside "src/autocomplete". Add the script to your html file and follow instructions above. Took me 1 minute to make it work.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could try add the attributes with the event "open":

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var jArrEl = $("a.ui-corner-all");
        jArrEl.addClass("myclass");
        jArrEl.attr("customattribute","something");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `create` event for autocomplete for newer versions. Like this:

```
create: function () {
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                var path = 'basepath' + item.value;
                return $('<li class="divSelection">')
                    .append('<div>')
                    .append('<img class="zoom" src="' + path + '" />')
                    .append('<span>')
                    .append(item.label)
                    .append('</span>')
                    .append('</div>')
                    .append('</li>')
                    .appendTo(ul); // customize your HTML
            };
        }
```

For full code review, I am attaching the way I bound autocomplete to my textbox.

```
$('.myTextBox').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {

            // your call to the server
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // when item is selected
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        },
        create: function () {
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                var path = 'basepath' + item.value;

                 return $('<li class="divSelection">')
                    .append('<div>')
                    .append('<img class="zoom" src="' + path + '" />')
                    .append('<span>')
                    .append(item.label)
                    .append('</span>')
                    .append('</div>')
                    .append('</li>')
                    .appendTo(ul); // customize your HTML
            };
        }
});
```

Comment: Please note that .append() function chain does not produce desired DOM. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387738/jquery-append-produced-out-of-order-html-elements-why