# jQuery .append() produced out of order html elements. Why?

Tags: jquery, append

My html contains this

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and when I do this in javascript

```
$("#container").append( '<div>' );
$("#container").append( '<p>' );
$("#container").append( 'test content' );
$("#container").append( '</p>' );
$("#container").append( '</div>' );
```

it produces this in the browser

```
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    "test content"
    <p></p>
</div>
```

instead of this

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
    <p>
    "test content"
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why are the div and p elements terribly out of order? It's obviously appending extra `</div>` and `</p>` elements that my code doesn't append. Why?

Comment: actually your code _does_ append those elements, because that's exactly what a browser should do with that code sequence.

Comment: Because it is not like building a string....

Comment: @epascarello exactly - it's building a tree of DOM elements, one at a time

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is creating a node whether the closing tag is explicitly specified or not and  `$("#container").append( '<div>' );` and `$("#container").append( '<p>' );`

What you need to do is either append to the new elements

```
$("#container").append( '<div>' );
$("#container div").append( '<p>' );
$("#container p").append( 'test content' );
```

or append the html together in one statement.

```
$("#container").append( '<div><p>test content</p></div>' );
```

Comment: The comments above are helpful. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: it's not really correct to say that jQuery is adding the closing tag.  In the background the code will do `document.createElement('div')` and that newly created element is already "closed".  If you then add notes to _that_ node, in the HTML they'll appear between the two tags.  When you consider the DOM as a tree of DOM elements and not as HTML, it should become clearer.

Comment: Good insight @Alnitak. I am not familiar with how jQuery accomplishes building the DOM. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The `.append` method can *only* insert *complete* HTML elements, not incomplete HTML fragments.

For elements that are not self closing this means that `.append('<div>')` will effectively append `<div></div>`.  In fact, in this case the `.append` method doesn't really append the HTML at all, it'll just call `document.createElement('div')` and then append that newly created node to the designated parent.

An alternative way to produce your desired content would be:

```
$('<div>').append($('<p>').text('test content')).appendTo('#container');
```