# Livesearch with jquery like autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have jquery live search and when I type something I see result but when I clicked result I want to see value in my input..and after I clicked out of the input result must be `display:none;` but like autocomplete I tried something but I couldn't apply it.

I don't use autocomplete plugin because I must show image in my result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#srehberText").keyup(function() {

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(),
      count = 0;
    if (!filter) {
      $(".commentlist li").fadeOut();
      return;
    }

    var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".commentlist li").each(function() {

      // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
      if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
      } else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
        count++;
      }
    });


  });
});
```

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
}

input {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #999;
}

li {
  display: none;
}

li img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font: 16px tahoma;
  padding: 4px;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #fffff0;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text-input" id="srehberText" placeholder="Bölgeyi yazmaya başla" />
<ol class="commentlist">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Germany</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Russia</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Turkey</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">England</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Netherlands</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">ABD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Korea</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: possible dupliation of question. 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746679/jquery-autocomplete-custom-html-for-result-listing  the answer was http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: I don't want to use jquery ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these, I made 2 options for you to try based on your code. I hope they help you achieve what you want.

Single select:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#srehberText").keyup(function() {

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(),
      count = 0;
    if (!filter) {
      $(".commentlist li").fadeOut();
      return;
    }

    var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".commentlist li").each(function() {

      // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
      if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
      } else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
        count++;
      }
    });


  });
});

$('.commentlist li a').click(function(){
  $('.commentlist').fadeOut();
  $("#srehberText").val($(this).text())
})
```

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
}

input {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #999;
}

li {
  display: none;
}

li img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font: 16px tahoma;
  padding: 4px;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #fffff0;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text-input" id="srehberText" placeholder="Bölgeyi yazmaya başla" />
<ol class="commentlist">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Germany</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Russia</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Turkey</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">England</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Netherlands</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">ABD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Korea</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Multi select:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#srehberText").keyup(function() {
    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(),
      count = 0;
    if (!filter) {
      $(".commentlist li").fadeOut();
      return;
    }

    var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".commentlist li").each(function() {

      // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
      if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
      } else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
        count++;
      }
    });


  });
});
var clicked = false;
$('.commentlist li a').click(function() {
  var val = $("#srehberText").val();
  if (!clicked) {
    val = "";
    clicked = true;
    $("#srehberText").val($(this).text())
  } else {
    $("#srehberText").val(val + " " + $(this).text())
  }

})

$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.commentlist, #srehberText').length) {
    if ($('.commentlist').is(":visible")) {
      $('.commentlist').hide();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
}

input {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #999;
}

li {
  display: none;
}

li img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font: 16px tahoma;
  padding: 4px;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #fffff0;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text-input" id="srehberText" placeholder="Bölgeyi yazmaya başla" />
<ol class="commentlist">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Germany</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Russia</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Turkey</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">England</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Netherlands</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">ABD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Korea</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code below checks where you click and if it's not `.commentlist, #srehberText` then it will hide the `ol`

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.commentlist, #srehberText').length) {
    if ($('.commentlist').is(":visible")) {
      $('.commentlist').hide();
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this would do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#srehberText").keyup(function() {

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(),
      count = 0;
    if (!filter) {
      $(".commentlist li").fadeOut();
      return;
    }

    var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".commentlist li").each(function() {

      // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
      if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
      } else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
        count++;
      }
    });


  });
  $(".commentlist li a").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).text();
    $("#srehberText").val(val);
    $('.commentlist li').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
}

input {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #999;
}

li {
  display: none;
}

li img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font: 16px tahoma;
  padding: 4px;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #fffff0;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text-input" id="srehberText" placeholder="Bölgeyi yazmaya başla" />
<ol class="commentlist">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Germany</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Russia</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Turkey</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">England</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Netherlands</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">ABD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Korea</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".commentlist li").click(function(){
     $("#srehberText").val($(this).text());
     // you have input box. that is why only text is inputed in side.
     // you will need to place small image control beside input to show image
  });
  $("#srehberText").keyup(function() {

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(),
      count = 0;
    if (!filter) {
      $(".commentlist li").fadeOut();
      return;
    }

    var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".commentlist li").each(function() {

      // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
      if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
      } else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
        count++;
      }
    });


  });
});
```

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
}

input {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #999;
}

li {
  display: none;
}

li img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font: 16px tahoma;
  padding: 4px;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #fffff0;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text-input" id="srehberText" placeholder="Bölgeyi yazmaya başla" />
<ol class="commentlist">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Germany</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Russia</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Turkey</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">England</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Netherlands</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">ABD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-flat-6/128/39_Email_Marketing-16.png">Korea</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `select` check it [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: Actually it is select2 i think.

Comment: I had used this plugin but input must behave autocomplete I don't any dropdown list but it's a good plugin

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan if it is then  `$(".js-example").select2();` is missing

Answer (score 0):

to make list invisible on  clicking somewhere else:

```
<input type="text" onblur="listHide()">

<script>
var molist = false; //mouse-over list
// make events mouseover and mouse leve to change molist value

function listHide() {
    if (molist = false) { //hide list}
}
</script>
```